# Given a solution of a Differential Equation. How to find the another solution in this exercise?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $y'''-x^2y'+xy=0$, solve the differential equation if $y_1=x$ is a solution.

I've tryed using the sustitution $y=u(x)y_1(x)=u(x) \cdot x$. Taking the derivates, the final form is like this:
$$(3u''+xu''')-x^2(u+xu')+x(u \cdot x)=0$$
$$3u''+xu'''-x^2u-x^3u'+ux^2=0$$
$$xu'''+3u''-x^3u'=0$$

But, now i have antoher D.E of degree 3. How i can find the another solution?.

Comment: Another solution is y=CX for any c. While this gives you another infinite number of solutions, I'm not sure this is what you meant to achieve.

Comment: the solution containes also the error function

Comment: Note that you reduced the degree of the DE: by subsituting $v=u'$ you have $xv''+3v'-x^3v=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You should get a second order equation for $u'$, not for $u$. Just to verity your calculation, we have

$$ y'(x) = u'(x) \cdot x + u(x), \\
y''(x) = u''(x) \cdot x + 2 u'(x), \\
y'''(x) = u'''(x) \cdot x + 3u''(x).
$$

Plugging this into the original equation we get

$$ u'''(x) \cdot x + 3 u''(x) - x^2 (u'(x) \cdot x + u(x)) + x^2 u(x) = u'''(x) \cdot x + 3u''(x) - x^3 u'(x) = 0 $$

which is a second order equation for $u'$. Explicitly, we can set $v = u'(x)$ and get the second order linear homogeneous equation

$$ v''(x) \cdot x + 3 v'(x) - x^3 v(x) = 0. $$

Dividing by $x$, we get the equation

$$ v''(x) + \frac{3}{x} v'(x) - x^2 v(x) = 0 $$

for which $x = 0$ is a regular singular point. Hence, a solution to this equation can be found using power series expansion of the form $v(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{n + r}$ where the coefficients $a_n$ and $r$ can be found by plugging this expansion into the equation.

Comment: @upvoters Did you check, even minimally, this approach before your vote?

Comment: @Did: Arg, sorry. I've messed this up originally but corrected it now.

Comment: Yes -- and now your answer reproduces (a part of) the question. What for?

Comment: @Did: Ok, I've at least included now a suggestion on how to solve the second order ODE...